# Finding the highest costing booking in MySQL database given start and end booking dates

Tags: mysql

I'm working on a class task in MySQL at the moment, and as part of this task, we have a few tables, although the ones relevant to this are called "booking", "room" and "room_type" (see below for generated sample data).

```
INSERT INTO `booking` (`bookingid`, `name`, `date_start`, `date_end`, `aname`) VALUES
(1, 'Holly Telfer', '2015-09-28', '2015-10-02', 'Pullman Brisbane King George Square'),
(2, 'Austin Creer', '2015-10-01', '2015-10-10', 'Pullman Brisbane King George Square'),
(3, 'Cooper Noble', '2015-10-11', '2015-10-15', 'Emporium Hotel');

INSERT INTO `rooms` (`room_name`, `aname`, `bookingid`) VALUES
('Standard Suite', 'Pullman Brisbane King George Square', 2),
('Premium Suite', 'Pullman Brisbane King George Square', 1),
('Penthouse', 'Emporium Hotel', 3);

INSERT INTO `room_type` (`rname`, `price`) VALUES
('Penthouse', 600),
('Premium Suite', 350),
('Standard Suite', 270);
```

What we have to do is use the start and end dates of the booking plus the price-per-night given in the room_type table to calculate the total price for each booking, and then return the booking with the highest total price (I will probably refer to the first query as a view). This is the query I have written so far, but it fails quite badly when run.

```
SELECT bookingid,DATEDIFF(date_end,date_start) * price AS total_price
FROM booking,room_type
WHERE date_start<=date_end AND date_end >=date_start
```

And this is the output:

```
"1","4200"
"2","3600"
"3","1200"
"1","2380"
"2","2040"
"3","680"
"1","4480"
"2","3840"
"3","1280"
"1","9100"
"2","7800"
"3","2600"
"1","1386"
"2","1188"
"3","396"
"1","1540"
"2","1320"
"3","440"
```

It's probably something stupidly simple but I just can't seem to wrap my head around why it's doing it, so if someone could point me in the right direction I would be very grateful. Thanks.

Comment: You need to JOIN all 3 tables otherwise you`ll get a cross JOIN

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to join the 3 tables and then write your logic bases on your requirement.

```
Select b.id,DATEDIFF(b.date_end,b.date_start) * rt.price from booking b
LEFT JOIN rooms r ON r.bookingid = b.bookingid
LEFT JOIN  room_type rt ON rt.rname = r.room_name
WHERE b.date_start <= b.date_end;
```

If have just copy pasted the conditions from your above query. You can change the SELECT statement to get the other results.